# Interpreting output from sklearn LDA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda

I'm using the sklearn LatentDirichletAllocation package to try to do some topic modeling.

My goal is to produce plots of how topics change over time in my corpus.

I'm trying to replicate the LDA portion of [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#example-applications-topics-extraction-with-nmf-lda-py), and so I have code that ends like this:

```
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=n_topics, max_iter=5,
                                learning_method='online',
                                learning_offset=50.,
                                random_state=0,
                                n_jobs=2)
t0 = time()
transformed_X = lda.fit_transform(tf)
```

When I look at transformed_X, it is an array of n_document arrays, each of length n_topics. I expected that each array would be the probability distribution of topics for that document, and that they would sum to 1. However, that isn't the case, and the sum of each array has a mean of 83. So, I'm wondering:

1. What do these values represent?
2. If I normalize values within an array, will that correspond to the topic probability distribution for that document?

Comment: Why don't you use fit instead of fit_transform?